# New OAuth2 needed to run script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I have been using this script to send google-spreadsheet to my e-mail when modified. Can anybody help to replace the authentication section with an OAuth2 for Apps Script. OAuth 1.0 support was deprecated in 2012 and is scheduled to be shut down on April 20, 2015.

Thanks.

```
function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [ {name: "Send Email", functionName: "sendEmail"}];
   ss.addMenu("Scripts", menuEntries);
 };


function sendEmail() {

  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();

  //var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();
   var email = Session.getEffectiveUser();

  var subject = "this is my subject";

  var body = "this is my body :)";



  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");

  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");

  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");

  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");

  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");

  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");



  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "oAuthServiceName": "google", "oAuthUseToken": "always"};




  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="

      + ssID + "&gid=0&portrait=true" +"&exportFormat=xls";



  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  

  var contents = result.getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]});

};
```

Comment: as per guidelines, show what you tried and didnt work. this is also already covered in existing s.o. answers if you search for them.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix. The fetch requests requires a scope allowing drive access. You can force Apps Script to add this scope by making a call to DriveApp. Then in your fetch you add the users OAuth token to the header of the call.

```
function onlyToAddTheDriveScope(){
  DriveApp.getRootFolder()
}

function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [ {name: "Send Email", functionName: "sendEmail"}];
   ss.addMenu("Scripts", menuEntries);
 };


function sendEmail() {

  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();

  //var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();
   var email = Session.getEffectiveUser();

  var subject = "this is my subject";

  var body = "this is my body :)";

  var requestData = {"method": "GET",
                     "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
                               };




  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="

      + ssID + "&gid=0&portrait=true" +"&exportFormat=xls";



  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  

  var contents = result.getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]});

};
```